# Probability a factor is odd

Tags: probability, factorial, factoring, parity

[image]

Take the above question. In the solution it says there 18 factors of 2 in the number. But how do they work this out? I see no reasoning or intuition between the line of working 10 + 5 + 2 + 1 = 18. Could someone please explain how they came to this conclusion in depth?

Comment: Cf. [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula).

Comment: Re the comment of @JohnOmielan, letting $~\lfloor r\rfloor~$ denote the largest integer $~\leq r,~$ consider $$\left\lfloor \frac{21}{2}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{21}{4}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{21}{8}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{21}{16}\right\rfloor = 18.$$  Therefore, the largest exponent $~\alpha~$ such that $~2^\alpha~$ divides $~[(21)!]~$ is $(18)$.  Therefore, the prime factorization of any randomly chosen factor will have a factor of $~2^\beta,~$ where $~\beta \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, 18\}.$  The factor will be odd if and only if $~\beta = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

They come to that because 10 numbers between 0 and 21 are even, half of those are divisible by 4. Just under half of those will be divisible by 8, and so on.